# Prevent program appearing in Add/Remove section of Control Panel

Tags: deployment, clickonce, bootstrapping, uninstallation, addremoveprograms

I'm bootstrapping a `ClickOnce` setup file so that I can add custom actions pre and post install. The only problem I'm facing is that the ClickOnce installation writes to the `Add/Remove Programs` section of `Control Panel`. This mean that the user would end up with two uninstallers (ClickOnce and my bootstrapper). I would like the program to be available offline, which rules out setting the ClickOnce deployment to online-only and suppressing the Add/Remove entry that way. Is there any other way to prevent a ClickOnce deploy from adding an entry to the Add/Remove section? Or is there a way to retrospectively remove the entry safely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its stored in the registry under

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Just delete the corresponding key and your good but it does sound a little malicious

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314481

Comment: Thanks! The reason I'm using a separate bootstrapper is because ClickOnce updates overwrite the files in the directory (which includes config and data files) + the hashes would no longer match if the data files are updated at runtime. Therefore, I write these files at runtime in a separate location. If the user was to uninstall using the standard ClickOnce uninstaller, these data files will remain on the machine and there's no way to manually delete them via code because you can't create custom actions with the ClickOnce uninstaller.